# asp.net on button click event not showing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

When i double click a button in asp to write click event....this appears instead of navigating to backend code of my website, what to do to resolve this

```
<script runat="server">

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: Show the [page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: it was page irective issue thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the following things specified in your page directive:

```
AutoEventWireUp="true"
```

and

```
CodeBehind="YourPage.aspx.cs"
```

So it will look something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Processing.aspx.cs" %>
```

Comment: and if web application ??

Comment: @PatrickHofman I hacked into the OP's machine and checked it out directly. Nah I'd pretty much guarantee that the issue is his page directive.

Comment: @mattytommo: Okay. Then you can be sure ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Looks like I was right :). Hacking machines helps after all :P